# Can someone please explain the query shown in depth?

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause

Question: write a SQL query to find the salespeople from the given tables who had more than one customer. Return `salesman_id` and `name`.

Sample table: `customer`

| customer_id | cust_name | city | grade | salesman_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3002 | Nick Rimando | New York | 100 | 5001 |
| 3007 | Brad Davis | New York | 200 | 5001 |
| 3005 | Graham Zusi | California | 200 | 5002 |
| 3008 | Julian Green | London | 300 | 5002 |
| 3004 | Fabian Johnson | Paris | 300 | 5006 |
| 3009 | Geoff Cameron | Berlin | 100 | 5003 |
| 3003 | Jozy Altidor | Moscow | 200 | 5007 |
| 3001 | Brad Guzan | London |  | 5005 |

Sample table: `salesman`

| salesman_id | name | city | commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5001 | James Hoog | New York | 0.15 |
| 5002 | Nail Knite | Paris | 0.13 |
| 5005 | Pit Alex | London | 0.11 |
| 5006 | Mc Lyon | Paris | 0.14 |
| 5007 | Paul Adam | Rome | 0.13 |
| 5003 | Lauson Hen | San Jose | 0.12 |

Solution

```sql
SELECT salesman_id,name 
FROM salesman a 
WHERE 1 < (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM customer 
           WHERE salesman_id = a.salesman_id);
```

So basically am unable to understand the subquery how can we compare two table column without using the joins and secondly how this where condition is working as a group by as well and provide the count. So if someone can help me understand this subquery in depth with easy language then it would be really helpful.

This question and solution is correct because am practicing on W3resource and you can find this question under the topic of SQL Subquery Exercises in the exercise 11.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a [correlated subquery](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations). In effect, the subquery is run once for each matching row of the outer table, using the join condition as filter criteria i.e. it will count for all rows with id = first id from outer table, then id = second id from outer table and so on. The resulting count for each id is then passed to the WHERE clause for filtering the rows of the outer table.

You could also write an equivalent query like so:

```
SELECT s.salesman_id,s.name 
FROM salesman a
INNER JOIN customer b
ON a.salesman_id = b.salesman_id
GROUP BY a.salesman_id
HAVING count(b.customer_id) >  1
```